# How To Send Multiple Keystrokes From Code Behind

Tags: c#, wpf

I am trying to send a compound keystroke from code behind.  By this I mean sending something like Ctrl+Tab.  I tried using KeyEventArgs as follows:

```
KeyEventArgs args1 = new KeyEventArgs(Keyboard.PrimaryDevice, Keyboard.PrimaryDevice.ActiveSource, 0, Key.LeftCtrl);
KeyEventArgs args2 = new KeyEventArgs(Keyboard.PrimaryDevice, Keyboard.PrimaryDevice.ActiveSource, 0, Key.Tab);
args1.RoutedEvent = Keyboard.KeyDownEvent;
args2.RoutedEvent = Keyboard.KeyDownEvent;
InputManager.Current.ProcessInput(args1);
InputManager.Current.ProcessInput(args2);
```

However, this is not working.  Does anyone know how I can do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do like this...

```
        var modKey = ModifierKeys.Control;
        var device = new MYKeyboardDevice(InputManager.Current)
        {
            ModifierKeysImpl = modKey
        };
        var keyEventArgs = device.CreateKeyEventArgs(Key.Tab, modKey);
```

**MYKeyboardDevice**

```
 public sealed class MYKeyboardDevice : KeyboardDevice
    {
        private sealed class MYPresentationSource : PresentationSource
        {
            Visual _rootVisual;

            protected override CompositionTarget GetCompositionTargetCore()
            {
                throw new NotImplementedException();
            }

            public override bool IsDisposed
            {
                get { return false; }
            }

            public override Visual RootVisual
            {
                get { return _rootVisual; }
                set { _rootVisual = value; }
            }
        }

        private static RoutedEvent s_testEvent = EventManager.RegisterRoutedEvent(
                "Key Event",
                RoutingStrategy.Bubble,
                typeof(MYKeyboardDevice),
                typeof(MYKeyboardDevice));

        public ModifierKeys ModifierKeysImpl;

        public MYKeyboardDevice()
            : this(InputManager.Current)
        {

        }

        public MYKeyboardDevice(InputManager manager)
            : base(manager)
        {

        }

        protected override KeyStates GetKeyStatesFromSystem(Key key)
        {
            var hasMod = false;
            switch (key)
            {
                case Key.LeftAlt:
                case Key.RightAlt:
                    hasMod = HasModifierKey(ModifierKeys.Alt);
                    break;
                case Key.LeftCtrl:
                case Key.RightCtrl:
                    hasMod = HasModifierKey(ModifierKeys.Control);
                    break;
                case Key.LeftShift:
                case Key.RightShift:
                    hasMod = HasModifierKey(ModifierKeys.Shift);
                    break;
            }

            return hasMod ? KeyStates.Down : KeyStates.None;
        }

        public KeyEventArgs CreateKeyEventArgs(
            Key key,
            ModifierKeys modKeys = ModifierKeys.None)
        {
            var arg = new KeyEventArgs(
                this,
                new MYPresentationSource(),
                0,
                key);
            ModifierKeysImpl = modKeys;
            arg.RoutedEvent = s_testEvent;
            return arg;
        }

        private bool RaiseEvents(UIElement target, RoutedEventArgs e, params RoutedEvent[] routedEventArray)
        {
            foreach (var routedEvent in routedEventArray)
            {
                e.RoutedEvent = routedEvent;
                target.RaiseEvent(e);
                if (e.Handled)
                {
                    return true;
                }
            }

            return false;
        }

        private bool HasModifierKey(ModifierKeys modKey)
        {
            return 0 != (ModifierKeysImpl & modKey);
        }
    }
```

Comment: How do you make the InputManager call?

Comment: You can pass the keyEventArgs and call the event handler, can you tell how you want to use this code ?

Answer (score 0):

What about SendKeys.SendWait("^{Tab}") ?

Add reference to, and using System.Windows.Forms

Use this as reference for other keystrokes: http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Send.htm

Answer (score 0):

[`Here`](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/b657618e-7fc6-4e6b-9b62-1ffca25d186b/problem-simulating-key-press-using-inputmanagercurrentprocessinput?forum=wpf) is a list of keys supported by `InputManager.InputProcess`, which can simulate:

```
None : True
Cancel : False
Back : True
Tab : True         <-------
... [Skipped] ...
LeftShift : False
RightShift : False
LeftCtrl : False   <-------
RightCtrl : False
```

I tried your example and <kbd>Tab</kbd> for me worked fine, but not with <kbd>LeftCtrl</kbd>. In this situation, I think it is necessary to look for alternatives. Besides, as I understand it, by this method (perhaps as other standard method) will not work to combine pressing multiple keys.

As one of the options:

[`WPF Sendkeys project`](http://wpfsendkeys.codeplex.com) - [*`Information about project`*](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kirillosenkov/archive/2010/07/09/wpf-sendkeys-or-mocking-the-keyboard-in-wpf.aspx)

This project provides `SendKeys` support for WPF UIElements (for in-process UI testing).

Answer (score 0):

How about just reacting on a "KeyUp" event, save the first key, check combination the second time you press a key, and if it matches one of your requirements do something?

That would be pretty simple to do..