# Wpf RichTextBox execute command by sending programmatic key strokes

Tags: c#, wpf, richtextbox, keystroke

I need to send keystrokes to a RichTextBox which at the end should execute some commands like ToggleBold or SelectAll etc.

I call the following code in a loop to iterate through `SomeEvent` and `SomeKey` pairs.

```
PresentationSource presentationSource = PresentationSource.FromVisual(RichTextBoxControl);

if (presentationSource == null)
{
    return;
}

if(SomeEvent == KeyDownEvent)
{
    //InputManager.Current.ProcessInput(new KeyEventArgs(Keyboard.PrimaryDevice, presentationSource, 100, SomeKey) { RoutedEvent = PreviewKeyDownEvent });
    InputManager.Current.ProcessInput(new KeyEventArgs(Keyboard.PrimaryDevice, presentationSource, 100, SomeKey) { RoutedEvent = KeyDownEvent });
}
else if (SomeEvent == KeyUpEvent)
{
    //InputManager.Current.ProcessInput(new KeyEventArgs(Keyboard.PrimaryDevice, presentationSource, 100, SomeKey) { RoutedEvent = PreviewKeyUpEvent });
    InputManager.Current.ProcessInput(new KeyEventArgs(Keyboard.PrimaryDevice, presentationSource, 100, SomeKey) { RoutedEvent = KeyUpEvent });
}
```

For example to activate ToggleBold I call following pairs in a loop:

```
KeyDownEvent, Keys.Control
KeyDownEvent, Keys.B
KeyUpEvent, Keys.B
KeyUpEvent, Keys.Control
```

I have tried `KeyDownEvent - KeyUpEvent`, `PreviewKeyDownEvent - PreviewKeyUpEvent`, and `PreviewKeyDownEvent - KeyDownEvent - PreviewKeyUpEvent - KeyUpEvent`, but none of them worked.

The RichTextBox actually catches the events but it does not react to them. This is also the case if I send alphanumeric characters (They are not printed on RichTextBox). However if I send `Keys.Back` it actually recognizes and deletes a character from the text.

The solutions like `SendKeys` and `keybd_event` are not applicable since the program will be on the background while the keystrokes are sent.

Is there a way to send keystrokes to a control like they really are sent by the user?

Answer (score 2):

**Update**

You asked

> Is there a way to send keystrokes to a control like they really are sent by the user?
>
> The solutions like `SendKeys` and `keybd_event` are not applicable since the program will be on the background while the keystrokes are sent.

From browsing the [WPF reference source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationFramework/Framework/System/Windows/Controls/RichTextBox.cs) it appears that it may not be possible to meet your requirement of doing this in the background:

1. When a `RichTextBox` is [constructed](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationFramework/Framework/System/Windows/Controls/RichTextBox.cs,d56d029cdc6abbca,references), a call is made to [`TextEditor.RegisterCommandHandlers()`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationFramework/Framework/System/Windows/Documents/TextEditor.cs,74809b82a16faade) to register global commands for the `RichTextBox` class, including the shortcuts.
2. `TextEditor.RegisterCommandHandlers()` in turn calls methods like [`TextEditorParagraphs._RegisterClassHandlers()`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationFramework/Framework/System/Windows/Documents/TextEditorParagraphs.cs,8a24ccca864b3aa6) to register specific commands for the class.
3. These in turn call [`CommandHelpers.RegisterCommandHandler()`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationFramework/Framework/MS/Internal/Commands/CommandHelpers.cs,f49cd1177244ef09) to register each command and associated (hardcoded) shortcut for the class.  The shortcuts are encoded as a [`KeyGesture`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationCore/Core/CSharp/System/Windows/Input/Command/KeyGesture.cs,b61d0c23332f4f26).
4. `RegisterCommandHandler()` in turn calls [`CommandManager.RegisterClassInputBinding()`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationCore/Core/CSharp/System/Windows/Input/Command/CommandManager.cs,94249f75453d928a) to register each shortcut gesture for the class.
5. The `CommandManager` stores the shortcut gestures in a [private static dictionary](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationCore/Core/CSharp/System/Windows/Input/Command/CommandManager.cs,e6d94726813bc908,references):

   ```
    private static HybridDictionary _classInputBindings = new HybridDictionary();
   ```
6. There is no "get" access to this dictionary.  The only other place it is used is in [`CommandManager.TranslateInput(IInputElement targetElement, InputEventArgs inputEventArgs)`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationCore/Core/CSharp/System/Windows/Input/Command/CommandManager.cs,78f53790a499f05c,references):

   ```
       // Step 2: If no command, check class input bindings
       if (command == null)
       {
           lock (_classInputBindings.SyncRoot)
           {
               Type classType = targetElement.GetType();
               while (classType != null)
               {
                   InputBindingCollection classInputBindings = _classInputBindings[classType] as InputBindingCollection;
                   if (classInputBindings != null)
                   {
                       InputBinding inputBinding = classInputBindings.FindMatch(targetElement, inputEventArgs);
                       if (inputBinding != null)
                       {
                           command = inputBinding.Command;
                           target = inputBinding.CommandTarget;
                           parameter = inputBinding.CommandParameter;
                           break;
                       }
                   }
                   classType = classType.BaseType;
               }
           }
       }
   ```
7. [`classInputBindings.FindMatch()`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationCore/Core/CSharp/System/Windows/Input/Command/InputBindingCollection.cs,afefa3bf8a150bcc) calls `KeyGesture.Matches()`.
8. But [`KeyGesture.Matches()`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationCore/Core/CSharp/System/Windows/Input/Command/KeyGesture.cs,762eca3ce8f962fd,references) uses the [*global static `Keyboard` device*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.keyboard%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) rather than the `InputEventArgs` to determine which key modifier is pressed:

   ```
   public override bool Matches(object targetElement, InputEventArgs inputEventArgs)
   {
       KeyEventArgs keyEventArgs = inputEventArgs as KeyEventArgs;
       if(keyEventArgs != null && IsDefinedKey(keyEventArgs.Key))
       {
           return ( ( (int)Key == (int)keyEventArgs.RealKey ) && ( this.Modifiers == Keyboard.Modifiers ) );
       }
       return false;
   }
   ```

   [`KeyEventArgs`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.keyeventargs%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) doesn't even have a property to represent whether a control or alt key is pressed.

If you remove the requirement to do this in the background, P/Invoking [SendInput](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17781021/c-sharp-p-invoke-how-to-simulate-a-keypress-event-using-sendinput-for-directx-ga) becomes a solution.

So I think the workaround of hardcoding commands may be your best solution.

**Original Answer**

Not *exactly* an answer to your specific question, but may solve your problem.

You can execute any of the [standard public static editing commands](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.documents.editingcommands%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) such as [`ToggleBold`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.documents.editingcommands.togglebold(v=vs.110).aspx) or [standard public static application commands](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.applicationcommands%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) such as [`Undo`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.applicationcommands.undo%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) by using

```
        command.Execute(null, richTextBox);
```

Where `command` is any of the static commands in the documentation linked above.  In addition, you can programmatically insert text at the current caret location using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2497291/how-do-i-move-the-caret-a-certain-number-of-positions-in-a-wpf-richtextbox)

```
        richTextBox.CaretPosition = richTextBox.CaretPosition.GetPositionAtOffset(0, LogicalDirection.Forward);

        richTextBox.CaretPosition.InsertTextInRun("Hello, I am some text\n\n\n");

        richTextBox.CaretPosition.InsertTextInRun("And some more text\n\n\n");
```

For instance, the following will insert some text at the current caret location of a specified `RichTextBox`, then animate various editing changes to all the text:

```
    const int delayInterval = 500;

    static void Do( RoutedUICommand command, RichTextBox richTextBox, ref int delay)
    {
        // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15599884/how-to-put-delay-before-doing-an-operation-in-wpf
        var timer = new DispatcherTimer { Interval = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(delay = delay + delayInterval)};
        timer.Start();
        timer.Tick += (sender, args) =>
        {
            timer.Stop();
            command.Execute(null, richTextBox);
        };
    }

    public static void TestTestProgrammaticCommandExecution(RichTextBox richTextBox)
    {
        // Insert some text at the caret position.
        // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2497291/how-do-i-move-the-caret-a-certain-number-of-positions-in-a-wpf-richtextbox
        richTextBox.CaretPosition = richTextBox.CaretPosition.GetPositionAtOffset(0, LogicalDirection.Forward);

        richTextBox.CaretPosition.InsertTextInRun("Hello, I am some text\n\n\n");

        richTextBox.CaretPosition.InsertTextInRun("And some more text\n\n\n");

        int delay = 0;

        // Do a bunch of editing commands.

        Do(EditingCommands.MoveToDocumentStart, richTextBox, ref delay);

        Do(EditingCommands.SelectToDocumentEnd, richTextBox, ref delay);

        Do(EditingCommands.AlignCenter, richTextBox, ref delay);

        Do(EditingCommands.AlignLeft, richTextBox, ref delay);

        Do(EditingCommands.AlignRight, richTextBox, ref delay);

        Do(EditingCommands.DecreaseFontSize, richTextBox, ref delay);

        Do(EditingCommands.IncreaseFontSize, richTextBox, ref delay);

        Do(EditingCommands.IncreaseFontSize, richTextBox, ref delay);

        Do(EditingCommands.IncreaseFontSize, richTextBox, ref delay);

        Do(EditingCommands.IncreaseFontSize, richTextBox, ref delay);

        Do(EditingCommands.Backspace, richTextBox, ref delay);

        Do(ApplicationCommands.Undo, richTextBox, ref delay);

        Do(EditingCommands.ToggleBold, richTextBox, ref delay);

        Do(EditingCommands.ToggleBold, richTextBox, ref delay);

        Do(EditingCommands.ToggleBold, richTextBox, ref delay);

        Do(ApplicationCommands.Undo, richTextBox, ref delay);

        Do(ApplicationCommands.Undo, richTextBox, ref delay);

        Do(ApplicationCommands.Undo, richTextBox, ref delay);

        Do(ApplicationCommands.Redo, richTextBox, ref delay);

        Do(ApplicationCommands.Redo, richTextBox, ref delay);

        Do(ApplicationCommands.Redo, richTextBox, ref delay);
    }
}
```

Comment: Actually I had already implemented this as a temporary solution. However this lacks the generality, since I have to parse the keys and find the corresponding command in a hardcoded way. Also, I am already using the Key and Event pairs to send keystrokes to the foreground program via `keybd_event`. (Sending my application or the foreground application is optional and selected by the user.). Therefore I want the two functionalities share the same structure behind.

Comment: @qqww2 - I thought you wrote that `keybd_event` was not applicable since the program is running in the background?

Comment: Thank you for putting your time to this problem. I looked into framework source and found that `Keyboard.Modifiers` resolves to `Keyboard.PrimaryDevice.Modifiers` and `Keyboard.PrimaryDevice` returns `InputManager.PrimaryKeyboardDevice`.  I thought [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21900546/3670437) might help , but I could not find any way to set the KeyboardDevice, it is set in the private constructor. Maybe reflection can solve this but I think it could be messier than hardcoding.